# Trying to hack the AWS IOS SDK so that it works for OSX. I get this error

Tags: objective-c, c

I've removed the import of the UIKit framework, and now I get this error.  Do I have to somehow recompile the framework?  It's not really giving me anything to go on...

And if it means anything, I am able to run the SDK examples in IOS so there aren't any system requirements that I'm not meeting.

```
ld: warning: ignoring file /Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.7.sdk/Library/Frameworks//AWSiOSSDK.framework/AWSiOSSDK, missing required architecture x86_64 in file
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_AmazonS3Client", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in Constants.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't just use the `.framework` provided by Amazon, because the binary is only for iOS. You need to rebuild the framework from the source, which thankfully comes in the SDK.

Answer (score 3):

I created a XCode project with the source from the iOS SDK that appears to work.  I have only tested some of the rudimentary S3 code but since it works in iOS, presumably, and I am able to communicate with S3, I think it should be good for all the services it supports.

https://bitbucket.org/danap/osx-aws-toolkit

Please feel free to fork and submit pull requests with changes.

Comment: Hey, I've just cloned your repo. got the following error.

dyld: Library not loaded: /Library/Frameworks/aws-toolkit.framework/Versions/A/aws-toolkit

Any idea where I'm doing wrong? (The project built & I added the framework and compiled. This is a runtime error.) Thanks Ants

Comment: I just got it going when just added the source to my project. Not sure what's up with the framework.

Answer (score 0):

I've created a fork of the AWS iOS SDK which can be built and used for Mac OS X development. Check it out: https://github.com/amberdixon/aws-sdk-ios. In the readme, I've included instructions on how to build the Mac OS X-compatible version of the AWS iOS SDK framework, which you can import into your OS X projects.