# How do I simply download an object from S3 in Mac OS X?

Tags: objective-c, macos, amazon-s3, amazon-web-services

After seeing [this question on aws](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9460804/aws-sdk-for-mac-os-x-application-development), I have downloaded the AWS iOS SDK and linked the .framework into my OSX app. If I try to import `AWSiOSSDK/S3/AmazonS3Client.h` into one of my classes, I now get a linker error for the classes whose header files are in the aws framework, and all I want to do is write a method to download a file from S3 and save it to a specific folder.

I tried setting up a TVM (token vending machine) on Elastic Beanstalk, but don't know how/if I should use it for authenticating, and I just can't seem to find documentation on how to download a file from S3 via a Mac App.

Currently if I try to access an S3 URL it fails due to missing credentials. I don't want to make the s3 files public, so I need to send creds with the request. Anyone who can point me in the right direction to get started or any guidance is appreciated!

Comment: Can you make the object `public-read` and fetch it using a standard HTTP client from `http://s3.amazonaws.com/bucket/object_name`? If not, why not? Please specify your access control requirements.

Comment: Sure, good point. No, I can't make it public because the files need to only be able to be downloaded when purchased. The s3 data needs to be fairly secure. I tried making an HTTP request to the url and of course got an error precisely because it is not public. So my problem is, to clarify: I need to be able to make a request WITH credentials to download a file from S3.

Comment: How about generating temporary, pre-signed urls server side ? From the app\s point of view it just sees a standard http url

Comment: How do you know when something is purchased? Can the component that decides "this thing is purchased" generate a pre-signed URL, as in [this query string authentication example](http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/s3-developer-guide/RESTAuthentication.html)?

Comment: I see that I can use an NSURLRequest with a header. Any clues as to how to calculate that canonicalized string from the amazon rest example? Should I post as a separate question perhaps...

Comment: @FrederickCheung sorry this is sort of new to me; are you suggesting building a separate web app to handle signing or is this something that can be done through AWS somehow?

Answer (score 1):

While it is not strictly an "SDK for OSX" you might find the AWS SDK for iOS a good starting point.

[SDK download](https://aws.amazon.com/sdkforios/)

[SDK source on GitHub](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-ios)

Comment: I mentioned the linker error I got with the iOS SDK - it doesn't run the same bit architecture as the mac app, and I was unclear as to how to fix this. Per [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7273944/1157631), I tried importing the src instead of the framework, but after wasting a ton of time pulling out all non-ARC code, it didn't seem an efficient use of time at all. Do you have any specific pointers on actual implementation of this idea? Seemed like a mess when I tried it.

Comment: I'm sorry, I obviously misread your question.  You will likely need to rebuild the SDK from source if you want to use it on Mac OS X.  You may find the [this blog post](http://mobile.awsblog.com/post/Tx3FHW3DMZ7MTJZ/Building-the-AWS-SDK-for-iOS-from-Source) of interest when building.